# How to display an html markup of a specific URL via cURL [php]

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to get content of a specific `URL` using cURL

```
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
   "http://stackoverflow.com//");
$output= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now I want to display markup just as text, I'm write the following code snippet:

```
<div class="content">
    <pre>
       <?php
            echo $output;
        ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

But when I'm trying to display markup there is no `div, pre` and others my markup's element. I can see the `stackoveflow.com` only. How to fix this?

Comment: @Quentin There is no executing of `echo $output` after executing curl request. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround your `$output` with [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) function to render tag output on your page.

Alternatively, you could make use of [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) as the former is pretty heavy.

So it would be like

```
<div class="content">
    <pre>
       <?php
            echo htmlentities($output);
        ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

---

**`EDIT :`**

> It doesn't work. This page is rendered as before.

That is because you need to set the `RETURNTRANSFER` **`cURL`** parameter to 1.

### The code...

```
<?php
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://stackoverflow.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$output= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
<div class="content">
    <pre>
       <?php
       echo htmlentities($output);
       ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This page is rendered as before.